# delete Object[key] inside template;

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Whether and how to delete a key from an object in Angular 2+ template?

Pseudo code:

```
    <span 
          (click)="delete objectName.keyName"> cancel 
   </span>
```

Comment: That code looks pretty good. Have you tested it?

Comment: Try to refrain from having logic in your template. Make a 'cancel' function instead that handles the logic.

Comment: @JackBashford no it's not, it is not possible to use the delete operator from the tempalte AFAIK

Comment: yes,He does not recognize it as a function

Comment: Then just make an event handler function that deletes the property for you.

Comment: `delete` will be treated as a class property

Comment: @TimVN i know but ask if it possible

Comment: Probably not. Maybe in some hackish way with ```eval```, though I'm not sure what the scope would be.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6h5sob?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<a (click)="delete()">Delete in component</a>
```

and then

```
delete() {
  delete this.objectName.keyName
}
```

In your template

If I try I get (click)="delete objectName.keyName"

Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'objectName' at column 8 in [delete objectName.keyName] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@0:12 ("]delete objectName.keyName">Delete in template